# How to make azure geo replication to support both side RW?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have two locations say primary (US) and secondary(UK) which are geographically dispersed locations (US and UK). I want to replicate files from US to UK and UK to US when ever data available in the corresponding location (file names manyn't be same, though).

One of the option, we thought is using Azure storage through which we can replicate primary data center files to secondary using RA-GRS (Read Access - Geo-Redundant Storage). But, as per requirement, I need secondary account side also to have Write and Read access which doesn't seems possible in existing replication types of Azure.

Hence, please let me know what would be appropriate replication/approach for this requirement.

Comment: RA-GRS is not even a possibility as the secondary location is decided by Azure based on the primary location plus secondary will always be read-only. You will need to roll out your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

None, you cant write to both regions with Azure storage. Its active\passive, basically. Active\Active sku do not exist yet.

Comment: how about creating two storage account one for Primary to Secondary and other one for Secondary (considering as Primary to enable Write) to Primary?

Comment: well, you can create your own solution as you would like, but there is nothing built-in, unfortunately.